# How to implement autocomplete for the following scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm looking for an `auto complete` solution for the following scenario:

My page has a `dropdownlist` and `textbox`:

```
   <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegions" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <label>Enter Iso:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtIso" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I need to implement `autocomplete` future for my `textbox` after 4 characters are entered.
Textbox will need to display some data based on option chosen from `dropdownlist`.

I need to display no more than 10 choices when typing in the values in `textbox`

I think I will need to use `jquery`, `ajax` and `webservice` call for that.

How can I accomplish something like that?

Thank's

Comment: jquery-ui autocomplete?

Comment: I'm new to all this, so I'm not sure what the difference between jquery-ui and others

Answer (score 0):

Simply download typeahead.js from the link as shown below and include in your application:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
Also, you have to include jQuery.

Comment: Thank's I will do that, but how should I use it to start showing some data only after 4 characters are typed and to show only 10 matches?

Comment: Ok, created a plunker for you at:
[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/dBFLMwKTWDoIF1LciWvJ?p=preview)

You can set minLength value as 4 to start searching after 4 characters.